# What is the best way to decompress a gzip'ed server response in Python 3?

Tags: gzip, python-3.x, urllib

I had expected this to work:

```
>>> import urllib.request as r
>>> import zlib
>>> r.urlopen( r.Request("http://google.com/search?q=foo", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"}) ).read()
b'af0\r\n\x1f\x8b\x08...(long binary string)'
>>> zlib.decompress(_)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#87>", line 1, in <module>
    zlib.decompress(x)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

But it doesn't. Dive Into Python [uses StringIO](http://diveintopython.net/http_web_services/gzip_compression.html) in this example, but that seems to be missing from Python 3. What's the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It works fine with `gzip` (gzip and zlib are the same compression but with different headers/"wrapping". Your error has this information in the message).

```
import gzip
import urllib.request

request = urllib.request.Request(
    "http://google.com/search?q=foo",
    headers={
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11", 
    })
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
gzipFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response)
gzipFile.read()
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone using Python 3.2 or later, there is an even simpler way to decompress a response than any of the answers here:

```
import gzip
import urllib.request

request = urllib.request.Request(
    "http://example.com/",
    headers={"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
result = gzip.decompress(response.read())
```

Comment: You should check if the response actually is encoded with gzip via `if response.getheader("Content-Encoding") == "gzip"`.

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3, [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO) is a class in the `io` module.

So for the example you linked to, if you change:

```
import StringIO
compressedstream = StringIO.StringIO(compresseddata)
```

to:

```
import io
compressedstream = io.StringIO(compresseddata)
```

it ought to work.

Comment: However for the answer, `BytesIO` is what's needed by the `fileobj` argument of `gzip.GzipFile` under Python 3.